# Windows 8.1 command line - input redirection not working

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1

everyone, I am trying to use the Windows command line for some little jobs. I was testing the input redirection, but it does not seem to work:

I created a test.txt file containing the following string:
`*.txt`

If I type: `dir /B *.txt` , I obtain a list of the .txt files in the directory.

If I type:  `dir /B < test.txt` , the result is equivalent to `dir /B` , i.e. it ignores the input redirection. The file was created with wordpad. Any idea on what is going wrong?

Thanks,

Max

Edit: If I try `dir /B $( < test.txt)` , an error message pops up: `The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: Input redirections does not work with `dir` because it simply does not expect Input from stdin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input redirection does not work with `dir` because it simply does not expect input from stdin. If it would react to stdin it would simply pause and wait for Input when you run `dir` without any Parameters.
If you want to read the pattern from a file do like this:

```
for /f %%i in (pattern.cfg) do set pattern=%%i
dir /b %pattern%
```

This will shove the last (or only) line from the pattern.cfg file into the variable pattern.

Comment: Thanks. I tested with "echo" and it seems not to work either. I am just trying to test a few commands, before running a job. One of this tests is to try and redirect std input from file. echo doesn't seem to take it either. Does it mean that input from file just does not work with all commands? What is a command that would work with it?

Comment: diskpart could work. But I think I did not yet understand what you want to achieve. Perhaps it is better if you create a temporary batch file you call from your primary batch

Comment: Well, thanks. That's a workaround. I am still puzzled that I cannot seem able to make use of input redirection, but at least this will do the job. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I just tried this and it worked no problem. Are you doing it in a batch file or from cmd?

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation but this worked for me:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in (test.txt) do set output=%i
dir /b %output%
```

Note that this will be fine directly on the command line, but in a batch file you should double up the '%' sign as seen in the above answer.